# Custom Java tool tip with Swing components as content does not show up

Tags: java, swing, layout, tooltip

I'm trying to show multiple images in a component's tooltip, found `createToolTip()` and implemented a custom that adds the needed components like this:

```
setComponent(component);

JPanel images = new JPanel(null);
images.setLayout(new BoxLayout(images, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
for(ImageIcon icon:myIcons) {
    images.add(new JLabel(icon));
}

JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
content.add(new JLabel(title), BorderLayout.NORTH);
content.add(new JLabel(description));
content.add(images, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

add(content);
```

However, all I see is a little dot, indicating that the tool tip is shown, but somehow the size is ignored. What do I miss implementing a custom tooltip?

Comment: nice question with great track-down :-) Just some link-dropping which might be interesting: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2128796 - see my last comment as to why the ui delegate ignores the LayoutManager

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The base "problems" are that JToolTip

- *is-not* designed as a container, it's only accidentally a container because JComponent is. For a Swing "not-container" its the responsibility of the ui-delegate to act as LayoutManager.
- isn't rich enough, it can handle text-only (at least with the emergency door html, which is @Andrew's favourite :-)

By-passing those limitations basically is a driving that widget nearly over the edge. A clean solution would roll a new component .. On the other hand, the OP already found the screws to tweak. The only thingy that could be slightly improved is to neither call setXXSize, nor set a custom ui. Instead, make it behave like a container by overriding getXXSize() like:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    if (getLayout() != null) {
        return getLayout().preferredLayoutSize(this);
    }
    return super.getPreferredSize();
}
```

Comment: Great! I added `!isPreferredSizeSet()` to the condition and are now using this variant!

Comment: And I see how the JToolTip is not really designed to do this, but don't quite understand why. As I see it, tooltips explain a component, but can even provide additional Info: I can see from the toolbar icon that the button print the document, but the tooltip additionally tells me that the acellerator is Ctrl+P. Facing that the tooltip may legitimately enhance a component's meaning, limiting it to text is surely historical? (Just wanted to get that out, no need to discuss a "philosophic" question here ;))

Comment: +1, this answer took me back to Swing Tutorials, seems like I missed too much, by reading this answer :-)

Answer (score 17):

Tool tips can render HTML.  If you can form URLs to the images (not practical if they are generated in memory but usually doable otherwise), it is an easy matter to write some HTML that will load the images, and use that HTML as the tool tip.

---

E.G.

[image: MultiIconToolTip]

```
import javax.swing.*;

class MultiIconToolTip {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String html =
            "<html><body>" +
            "<img src='" +
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOg3.jpg" +
            "' width=160 height=120> " +
            "<img src='" +
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxthA.jpg" +
            "' width=160 height=120>" +
            "<p>Look Ma, no hands!";
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JLabel hover = new JLabel("Point at me!");
                hover.setToolTipText(html);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, hover);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest to using `JWindow` or un_decorated `JDialog`, as popup window (used by default for `JCalendar` or `JDatePicker`) rather than `JTooltip`, for nicer output to the GUI implements [Translucent and Shaped Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)

---

**NOTE**:
If you use JDK 1.6 or older, use [this method](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/translucent-shaped-windows-139324.html) instead.
It only works with SUN JDK.

Comment: "EDIT": I just took Oracle's transparency source and added the shape source portion, so you have both in a short demo class: http://pastebin.com/pcPArzRH

Answer (score 3):

There are essentially two things missing. First of all, `JToolTip` extends `JComponent`, and unlike `JPanel`, it doesn't have a default layout. To stretch the `content` across the tooltip, use a `BorderLayout`.

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

The second problem is the size. The `ToolTipManager` respects the preferred size of the tool tip. While the `BorderLayout` calculates the size, the `ToolTipUI` ignores it. So, there are two alternatives: Manually set the preferred size...

```
setPreferredSize(content.getPreferredSize());
```

Note that this does not make the layout obsolete; otherwise, you get an empty tool tip with the right size.

... or subclass `ToolTipUI` to respect the layout, which is what I went with. The resulting code is:

```
setComponent(StadtLabel.this);

JPanel images = new JPanel(null);
waren.setLayout(new BoxLayout(waren, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
for(ImageIcon icon:myIcons) {
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel(icon);
}

JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
content.add(new JLabel(title), BorderLayout.NORTH);
content.add(new JLabel(description));
content.add(images, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(content);
setUI(new ToolTipUI() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize(JComponent c) {
        return c.getLayout().minimumLayoutSize(c);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
        return c.getLayout().preferredLayoutSize(c);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize(JComponent c) {
        return getPreferredSize(c);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel try this: https://github.com/timmolderez/balloontip. You can put any content as JComponent.

Comment: With the demise of java.net, I believe that BalloonTip is now on [github](https://github.com/timmolderez/balloontip).