# use of icons on ToolTipText

Tags: java, swing, icons, tooltip, jlabel

Basically, I need an image/icon to show up whenI hover over a swing component

```
//this is what i normally use to apply image to components
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("icon.png"));
label = new JLabel(icon);
```

what I'd like to do:

```
 //use an imported icon on a tool tip text and also add some texts
 label.setToolTipText(icon + "some random text");
```

Comment: don't bother with the spelling when it comes to programming.

Comment: tell stack overflow's spell checking that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tool tips support HTML, so display that image as you might display it in HTML.  E.G. as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9523186/418556).

[image]

Comment: i dont know that programming language

Comment: HTML is not a programming language.

Comment: ok i got it to work, but how do i replace the links to the picture on the internet by links to pictures in a folder on my computer, iv tried everything i know about links but it just wont do it

Comment: *"how do i replace the links to the picture on the internet by links to pictures in a folder on my computer"*  Use what you originally used.  `getClass().getResource("icon.png")`  What do you think that returns, a pony?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think he means the image links in the HTML.  The tooltip, not his icon.  (and yeah, it wasn't part of his original question)